# Restrict ssh by host key fingerprint

Tags: openssh

Is there a way with OpenSSH (`ssh`) to specify the expected host key fingerprint as a command-line argument so that a connection will only be allowed if the key fingerprint sent by the server matches the one given as a command line argument ?

I am trying to provide a similar level of functionality in Windows and Posixly versions of application. On Windows, the usual SSH client is `plink` (also available on Linux) which has a `--hostkey` command-line option for this purpose:

```
$ plink -hostkey "d0:e4:ad:11:7d:6a:8c:c0:36:2b:ff:ee:16:cf:f7:46" user@host
```

Is that possible with the OpenSSH `ssh` command ?

Comment: By default no; I guess you could write a wrapper script that disables the default `known_hosts` lookups, accepts the supplied key (or keys?) writes that to a temporary file, then `exec ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=$URTMPFILE ...`

Answer (score 6):

You could set the expected key in `known_hosts` before running ssh, but I think you'd need the whole key then, not just the fingerprint.

But ssh prints the key fingerprint when connecting if it isn't saved in `known_hosts`, so we could use that and `expect` our way out of it.

The script here would take the hostname (or `user@host`) and expected fingerprint as arguments, force an empty `known_hosts`, and compare the printed fingerprint to the given one.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set host   [lindex $argv 0];
set fp     [lindex $argv 1];

spawn ssh -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null $host
expect -indices -re "key fingerprint is (\[^.\]+)"
set fp_got $expect_out(1,string)

expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)"
if { $fp_got == $fp } {
        send "yes\r"
} else {
        send "no\r"
}       
interact
```

So, given the correct fingerprint, the connection should succeed:

```
$ ./ssh.expect localhost 60:6e:...:e1 
spawn ssh -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 60:6e:...:e1.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
itvirta@localhost's password:
```

Comment: Note OpenSSH since 6.8 fingerprint display defaults to base64 (of SHA256) no longer hex with colons (of MD5). Putty/plink/etc hasn't followed suit.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, right, I had a vague memory of that, but didn't happen to have a new enough version at hand. I changed the pattern to assume less of the format.